# Using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf - I am having trouble passing data from template to controller back to template

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

New to Spring/REST and getting this error after creating a new attorney, I have an attorney table with a firstName field mapped appropriately. The print statement outputs the current data. I am not sure why the data is not getting to the template. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on null
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object create(@ModelAttribute Attorney attorney, @Valid Login login, @Valid Firm firm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    try {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("createdAttorney", attorney);
            model.addAttribute("InitialLogin", login);
            model.addAttribute("firm", firm);
            return "views/register";
        } else {
           // login.setAttorneyEmailAddress(attorney.getEmailAddress());
           // login.setAttorneyId(attorney.getAttorneyId());
            this.attorneyService.save(attorney);
            System.out.println(attorney);
            model.addAttribute("att", attorney);
            return "redirect:/attorney";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error Registering " + ex.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my "redirect: /attorney" info:

```
 Attorney <p th:text="${att.firstName}"></p> Summary Page
```

Comment: No public getter on Attorney for firstName?

Comment: yea, I tried using the getter for firstName as well. I have the same issue - I can access it from the server side but not the template.

Comment: Hello BluLotus can you please paste your html file as well

Comment: Must be getting a different Attorney class in the template then, and yes, returning Object is a bit strange. Might be a problem there.

Comment: @Pradeep I used ModelandView instead and the data is there but still not in the view `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>

    <title>Attorney Summary</title>

</head>
<body>
<div th:text="${firstName}"></div>
Attorney <div th:text="${att}"></div> Summary Page
<tr th:each="users : ${att}">
    <td th:text="${users.firstName}">1</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html> `

Comment: did you saw my answer ?have you followed the step 2

Comment: yes I did this:   
            `ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("vies/register");
                model.addObject("firstName", attorney.getFirstName());
                System.out.println(attorney.getFirstName());
                model.addObject("att", attorneyService.findAll());`

Comment: Hello BluLotus,Hope my answer helped you .If yes please accept the answer if not please let me know so that I can improvise on that and help you to give  a better solution.

Comment: thanks for following up @Pradeep I was able to solve this issue by passing in the object to the view controller it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1)

> In your html file  add `<form:form>` tag so that you can add model
>   attribute

Step 2)

> You should return Model View instead of Object from your controller .

Create ModelView object in your controller and try returning the ModelView

```
ModelView model=new ModelView();
model.addAttribute("att", attorney);
```

Step **1** is not mandatory try using Step 2 alone ,if it doesn't work try both

Comment: I resolved this issue - I was not passing the object into the method mapped to the /attorney view. Thanks for all the feedback on this, though!

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
model.addAttribute("att", new Attorney());
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to return ModelAndView object in your method instead of Object ?